# REST call response HTTPS Status 415

Tags: json, rest, http-status-code-415

Please find below my controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reconrangesummary", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getReconRangeSummaryReport(@RequestBody RequestData requestData){
    logger.info("Inside Interest Service Controller - getReconRangeSummaryReport");
    List<ReconRangeSummaryDetails> reconRangeSummaryDetails = new ArrayList<ReconRangeSummaryDetails>();
    DashboardRequestDetails requestDetails = AccountUtils.convertRequest(requestData);
    reconRangeSummaryDetails = accountService.getReconRangeSummaryDetails(requestDetails);
    logger.info("Exit Interest Service Controller - getReconRangeSummaryReport");

    return new Gson().toJson(reconRangeSummaryDetails);

}
```

Request Data Class:

```
public class RequestData {

private String role;
private String branchCode;
private String circle;
private String requestDate;
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public String getBranchCode() {
    return branchCode;
}
public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
}
public String getCircle() {
    return circle;
}
public void setCircle(String circle) {
    this.circle = circle;
}
public String getRequestDate() {
    return requestDate;
}
public void setRequestDate(String requestDate) {
    this.requestDate = requestDate;
}
```

I am passing the below request in postman with **POST method and content-type:application/json**.

```
{"role":"makeruser", "branchCode":"00112", "circle":"circlename", "requestDate":"17-12-2018"}
```

But I am getting error response as below.

***HTTP Status 415 

The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().***

Comment: Could this all be coming from your `requestDate` format? I was fighting with the same issue a couple of days ago and for me that was the solution.

Comment: I dont think that could be an issue. Adding the RequestData class also in the main thread for your info.

Comment: Ok. What does Postman give as the hard data it sends? You can see that with the Code link below the Send button.

Comment: Hi JussiV, Please find below the info.                                                          

POST /scfu_dashboard_services/reconrangesummary HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 15fc05d5-c56d-8975-274f-86c74176b1b1

{
"role":"makeruser",
"branchCode":"00112",
"circle":"circlename",
"requestDate":"17-12-2018"
}

Answer (score 0):

When Posting your request you have to specify JSON/Application media type in this case too.
If you use Postman, change the following checkbox:[image]

Or a command line version if you want:

```
curl -d '{"role":"makeruser", "branchCode":"00112", "circle":"circlename", "requestDate":"17-12-2018"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9009/new/reconrangesummary
```

Comment: In postman, I posted the request as you have mentioned only. By choosing war and JSON(application/json). Ending up with same error response

Comment: Can you post your output for curl? Also I would recommend to make sure that your body in UTF8 encoding and change you endpoints to  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_URF8  for consistancy